# How to check for OpenSSL Oracle Vulnerability for internal application?

Tags: security, apache-http-server, openssl

I am trying to test our internal applications(DEV and QA enironments) which are behind the firewall for OpenSSL Oracle Vulnerability. I am able to run Qualys(ssllabs.com) to check for Oracle Vulnerability of our production application. Am wondering are there any such free tools/methods to check for Oracle Vulnerability of internal applications?